# angular.copy(src,dest) vs dest=angular.copy(src)

Tags: angularjs

Why not always do `dest=angular.copy(src)` instead of `angular.copy(src,dest)`

I have src value as `parentObj.childObj={a:1}`

I have defined `tgtParentObj.tgtChildObj={}` but I have not defined `tgtParentObj.tgtChildObj.tgtGrandChildObj` (currently undefined)

This does not work: `angular.copy(parentObj.childObj   tgtParentObj.tgtChildObj.tgtGrandChildObj)`

But this works: `tgtParentObj.tgtChildObj.tgtGrandChildObj = angular.copy(parentObj.childObj)`

Question: Why not always do `dest=angular.copy(src)` if that creates a deep copy as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `dest = angular.copy(src)` if you want.

1. When you use `dest = angular.copy(src)` this create a deep copy of your `src` and put this on the `dest` object.
2. When you use `angular.copy(src, dest)` it replaces all properties, values and so on, on the `dest` object. That's why this doesn't work if the `dest` does not exists.

See more on angular documentation for the [copy function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Comment: Thanks. Will just use dest = angular.copy(src)  in that case